# Get variable from current div for getJSON statement

Tags: jquery, json, modal-dialog

I have a page with multiple divs with the same class. I want to open a modal window and then fill the modal with JSON/dynamic content. For that I need to get the correct url to use in the getJson statement. So I have a page with multiple products, like so:

HTML

```
<div class="product" style="opacity: 1;">
   <a title="product" **href="url-to-product.com"**>..................</a>
   <h3><a href="url-to-product.com">Blabla</a></h3>
   <div class="button opener">...</div>
</div>
<div class="product" style="opacity: 1;">
   <a title="product" **href="other-url-to-product.com"**>..................</a>
   <h3><a href="other-url-to-product.com">Blabla</a></h3>
   <div class="button opener">...</div>
</div>
```

When I click the button a modal pops up. Now I want to fill that modal with content. Therefore I need the href value between the ** **. Only the one from the current clicked product offcourse. So what I have is this:

JQUERY

```
 $(".opener").live("click", function(event) {
     event.preventDefault();
          $.get($(this).attr('href'), function(data, status) {
            $("#dialog").dialog("open");

            var url = $(this).find('h3 > a').attr('href');
```

// this doesn't work and needs to be the value from the href like mentioned above

```
            $.getJSON(url, function(data) {                          
              $.each(data.product, function(index, product){ 
              ......... etc .......
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `siblings()` selector to get the sibling of the div element.

```
var url = $(this).siblings('a').attr('href');
```

or

```
var url = $(this).siblings('h3').children('a').attr('href');
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to fetch data using `href` attribute from hte `div.opener`, not from the `.product > a`.

Try this code:

```
$(".opener").live("click", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var url = $(this).parents('.product').find(' > a').attr('href');

    // do whatever you need using the url you wanted to get
}
```